# unsigned char[], bits or bytes?

Tags: c

I'm  writing some kind of protocol to transmit with the NRF24 module so, the procotol is declared like this:

```
unsigned char protocol[16];
```

that protocol have 16bits or 16bytes size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16 bytes. 1 char is generally 1 byte on most systems.

Comment: Nitpick; `char` is definitionally a byte. A byte might not have 8 bits, though.